# Using a connector to crawl content using a sitemap.xml

Tags: google-search-appliance, dspace

We have a dspace repository of research publications that the gsa is indexing via a web crawl, ie start at the homepage and follow all the links.

I'm thinking that using a connector to submit urls for indexing from sitemap.xml file, might be more efficient.  The gsa would then only need to index and recrawl the urls on the sitemap and could ignore the result of the site.

The suggestion from the gsa documentation is that this is not really a target for a connector, as the content can all be discovered by a web crawl.

What do you think?

Thanks, 
Georgina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be outdated (so I'm not sure if it still work), but there's an example of a python connector that will parse a sitemap.xml and send it as Content Feed or Metadata feed.
Here are 2 links to help you
https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit/blob/master/connectormanager/sitemap_connector.py

https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit/wiki/ConnectorManagerDocumentation

If anything, this will give you an idea of the logic to implement if you write your own Connector 3.x or Adaptor 4.x

Comment: I have downloaded the gsa-admin-toolkit and found the sitemap_connector.py and was keen to try it.  I wasn't aware that it was old and might not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate sitemaps making from /bin directory "dspace generate-sitemaps". It will generate a sitemaps directory with link to all items from dspace.

An output example:

```
   <html><head><title>URL List</title></head><body><ul><li><a href="http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/1">http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/2">http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/3">http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/5">http://localhost:8080//handle/123456789/5</a></li>
</ul></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a GSA "Feed" that lists the URLs that you want to crawl.  However, since your "Follow" patterns must include the host name of your web site, the crawler is going to follow all the pages that are linked from the pages in your feed.

If you truly only want to index the items in your "Site Map" then you should probably look at writing an [Adaptor (4.x)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/connectors/40/410/GSAConnectorsDeveloperGuide.pdf).  You would then be responsible for writing the logic to parse your sitemap.xml file to extract the URLs you want crawled.